# whois domain privacy is enabled but private info still shows in google search results

Tags: privacy, whois

I enabled domain privacy two months ago, but when I do a google search like this: "myname" mywebsite.com , I find a search result link like this:

mywebsite.com WHOIS, DNS, & Domain Info...
whois.domaintools.com/mywebsite.com
Admin: myname Owner: myAddress_and_personal_info

And when i click on the link all my info is in fact private, the registrant info shows up like this in who.is/whois/mywebsite

Registrant City: Nobby Beach
Registrant State/Province: Queensland
Registrant Postal Code: QLD 4218
Registrant Country: AU
Registrant Phone: +45.36946676
Registrant Phone Ext: 
Registrant Fax: 
Registrant Fax Ext: 
Registrant Email: Email Masking Image@privacyprotect.org

How do I prevent my personal information from showing up in google search results if I have domain privacy enabled? Does this not defeat the purpose of using domain privacy protection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your information was visible before you enabled whois privacy, Google probably spidered it then and you're seeing the results they found. You might be able to convince Google to remove it if you have a good reason to, but if your only reason is that you don't want the information visible anymore you'll most likely have to wait until Google spiders the Whois site again and replaced the old information with the current contents.

Google results and whois privacy are two unrelated things. The purpose of whois privacy is to insure nobody looking up your domain in the Whois system can see your private information, not to insure that nobody in the world remembers what was there originally.

Comment: The information was visible before whois privacy was enabled and it is unlikely google will remove phone and address information based on their removal policy...https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2744324  Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that your whois privacy "works" i.e. provides complete anonymity to the public in terms of the domain record, you have to set whois privacy on upon registration of the domain. Otherwise sites like http://domaintools.com and http://domainbigdata.com will have the chance to pick it up, and then store it in a publicly available format.